# Can't get column to display value as "blanks" when they do not exist in table

Tags: sql

I am joining two tables.  Both tables contain some columns with the same names. This is why I am using the STUFF function.

My query seems to run fine except that the J_Link column keeps populating the same value.  It's a problem because the other users shouldn't have a J_Link value because they are not in the GOTJ_NI table for that date range.

```
Employee_NAME = STUFF

((SELECT N', ' + Employee_NAME FROM [LBA_DATA].[dbo].[GOTA_NI]
WHERE A.[Date_A] =[Date_A] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N''),

J_Link,
A_Link

FROM [LBA_DATA].[dbo].[GOTA_NI] as A JOIN [LBA_DATA].[dbo].[GOTJ_NI] as CU on A.Type_A = CU.Type_J
where (CU.Date_J>= DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE()))
AND (A.Date_A>= DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE()))
```

---

RESULT of SQL query

```
Employee_Name   J_Link   A_Link

"Tom"           2421     24225
"Steve"         2421     24228
"Chris"         2421     24233
"Kim"           2421     24231
```

My expected result is that the J_Link column only has a value for the employee named Chris. So I'd like blanks where where employees don't have this value. Also Chris should not have an A_Link record so I'd like blanks where employees do not have a value set.

My expected result would look like this:

```
Employee_Name   J_Link   A_Link

"Tom"                    24225
"Steve"                  24228
"Chris"                  24233
"Kim"           2421
```

Comment: Make sure to use SO's code functionality to make the readability of your SQL code better. you can use the accent mark or four spaces to move it into a code block.

Comment: Can you share a snapshot of your original table? And the result that you expect

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I have posted my expected result.